Does windows 11 (latest update today) need microsoft visual C++ redistribution 2005-2012?
basic info
Create date : 2024/12/31
Time that occur : 2024/12/29
What happened?
At 2024/12/29, cursor in my notebook got stuck when I move my cursor. Then I tried to look info with task manager. In task manager, it says that my CPU utilization is about 40% which is little high.
So,
I uninstall these app from setting -> installed apps :

Python

Microsoft visual C++ redistribution 2005-2012

MySQL server

MySQL workbench

Movie

Painter 2D

Windows update healther

Eclipse

OneLineCommander

IntelliJ

etc


Then my app still got crash more often
(ocurred when open project with VSC and ME stands for microsoft edge)
And I heard a huge noise when the notebook is powering on.
Further questions:

Is Microsoft visual studio redistribution  2005-2012 built-in for Windows 11 in Windows 11?

Does Windows 11 need microsoft visual studio redistribution 2005-2012

What is that?


What I did try?
Google and visit these websites
Microsoft visual c++ redistribution 2005-2012 (chinese version)
Microsoft visual c++ redistribution 2005-2012 (english version)

It would need these old versions of the Visual Studio Redistributable if you have old software installed on your machine that needs these versions. In either case having these redistributables installed should not likely cause any type of performance problem. If you really want you can uninstall them and see if any of your old software is broken after the uninstall. If not perhaps you no longer have the old software installed that required them.

Also note that you can't fix the computer by uninstalling software.

it says that my CPU utilization is about 40% which is little high Go into Task Manager and figure out what program is using your CPU.
